# Multiple attributes in activeadmin associated dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am using **Active Admin** where I have two models **User** and **Post**. The relationship is User has many Post and Post belongs to User. The attributes of User are `name, id, phone-number, email and address`. In new form of Post, associated dropdown of User is only showing name of each user but I want to show `name,phone-number and address` of every user. I am new to RoR. So any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the associated dropdown you should edit your form association's input in the ActiveAdmin form. ActiveAdmin uses [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) to generate forms for your models. When you set your User model in your Post's form as `f.input :user` ActiveAdmin set the input type to `:select`.

So, you can use `f.input :user, as: :select` and it'll work in the same way.

[Formtastic Select](https://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/SelectInput) let us edit the label rendered in each option through the `member_label` property. First add the property to your input in the ActiveAdmin form
`f.input :user, member_label: :full_label`, then declare the `full_label` method in your User model returning the joined string with the user attributes.

```rb
def full_label
  "#{name} - #{phone-number} - #{address}"
end
```